# Refresh view in iPhone navigation based application

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I am using a navigation based application for iPhone. I want to reload a view when i come back to it after pressing the back button. ANy solution?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Add a method **viewWillAppear:** to your controller class. In that method you can then update the view with current data.

The **viewWillAppear:** method will execute whenever the view is about to be displayed (after navigating to a different view using UINavigationController)

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one, but I usually use NSNotificationCenters. You attach "listeners" for some kind of event, like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(onSomethingChanged:)
     name: @"somethingChangedEvent"
     object: nil];
```

So, if some other view changes a setting, it notifies all the listeners like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"somethingChangedEvent" object: Nil];
```

Pretty simple and intuitive.